# SQL statement dynamically using current time to choose a time frame in a field (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, case, between

All, I have something that is stumping me and I have seen a lot of examples, but nothing is helping solve this.
I have time frames like 03:30:00 to 11:29:59 that I work with (say shift times).  I want to dynamically query data for the last shift based on the current shift.
Example: if it is currently between 11:30:00 AM and 7:29:59 PM, I want get the last shift that was between 03:30:00 AM and 11:30:00 AM.

This would look like an if statement in my mind:
    If time between .... then
     select time between....
    elseif time between.... then
     select time between...

I tried many combinations and can't figure this out.  I think I would need a CASE and maybe a subquery? or maybe DECODE will work?

```
SELECT CAST(ccd.DATEc AS TIME) as time_occured,
FROM db.datatb ccd
WHERE ccd.DATE > SYSDATE - interval '1440' minute
AND (
((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss')BETWEEN '03:30:00' AND '11:29:59' IN (SELECT 
ccd.DATEc FROM db.datatb WHERE (CAST(ccd.DATEc AS TIME)NOT BETWEEN '03:30:00 
AM' AND '07:29:59 PM')))
OR (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss')BETWEEN '11:30:00' AND '19:29:59' IN 
(SELECT ccd.DATEc FROM db.datatb WHERE (CAST(ccd.DATEc AS TIME) BETWEEN 
'03:30:00 AM' AND '11:29:59 AM')))
OR (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss')NOT BETWEEN '03:30:00' AND '19:29:59' IN 
(SELECT ccd.DATEc FROM db.datatb WHERE (CAST(ccd.DATEc AS TIME) BETWEEN 
'11:30:00 AM' AND '07:29:59 PM')))
)
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type.

Comment: Example data from your database would help a lot. Do you have dates too, or time only? Is there a possibility of overlapping shifts (03:30:00 - 11:30:00 vs 07:00:00 - 15:00:00?

Comment: Do you have a sample of what the data in the table looks like?

Comment: It is a timestamp type with date included: 2017-04-19 06:19:46

Comment: no possibility of overlapping shifts. They are 3:30:00 - 11:29:59, 11:30:00 to 19:29:59 and 19:29:59 to 3:29:59 the next day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   db.datatb
       CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '210' MINUTE )
                + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
                   TRUNC(
                     ( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '210' MINUTE
                     - TRUNC( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '210' MINUTE )
                     ) * 3
                   ) * 480
                   + 210,
                   'MINUTE'
                 ) AS current_shift_start
         FROM    DUAL
       ) css
WHERE  DATEc >= css.current_shift_start - INTERVAL '8' HOUR
AND    DATEc <  css.current_shift_start;
```

**Explanation**:

The shifts are 8 hours each starting at 03:30 (or 210 minutes past midnight); so `SYSDATE - INTERVAL '210' MINUTE` will move offset the times so that after this offset they start at 00:00, 08:00 and 16:00 which is thirds of a day.

`date_value - TRUNC( date_value )` calculates the fraction of a day (between 0 and 1) that the time component represents; so `TRUNC( ( date_value - TRUNC( date_value ) ) * 3 )` maps that fraction of the day to 0, 1 or 2 corresponding to whether it is in the 1st, 2nd or 3rd 8 hour period of the day. Multiple that value by 480 minutes and then add the 210 minutes that the date was originally offset by and you have the minutes past the start of the day that the shift starts.

Comment: Can you provide some information about what the above statement does?

Comment: This worked!  I would love to get a bit of an explanation about it though in case I need to do more work on it.  Thanks for your help MTO!

Comment: @LKMS Explanation added.